# Incorrect first value when using dense_rank with union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to 'batch' my result (coming from a union of several queries) with a predefined 'batch size' but I can't figure out why the first batch is always incorrect?

For instance with the following code:

```
DECLARE @BATCHSIZE AS INT =  2;

DECLARE @TEMPTABLE  TABLE(ITEMID  VARCHAR (10))
INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLE VALUES ('100'),('200'),('300'),('400'),('500'),('600'),('700'),('800'),('900'),('1000'),('1100'),('1200'),('1300'),('1400'),('1500')
;

WITH TEMP AS
(
SELECT * FROM @TEMPTABLE
) 

SELECT *, BatchId = (dense_rank() over (order by ITEMID) / @BatchSize + 1)
 FROM (
SELECT * From TEMP
UNION ALL
SELECT * From TEMP

) AS temptable
```

I get a result:

```
100 1
100 1
1000    2
1000    2
1100    2
1100    2
1200    3
1200    3
1300    3
1300    3
1400    4
1400    4
1500    4
1500    4
200 5
200 5
300 5
300 5
400 6
400 6
500 6
500 6
600 7
600 7
700 7
700 7
800 8
800 8
900 8
900 8
```

It seems like they're all ok except for batch 1 which only consist of itemid 100?
Must be doing something wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dense_rank()` starts with 1. Shift it to start with 0 :

```
...
SELECT *, BatchId = (dense_rank() over (order by ITEMID) - 1 )/ @BatchSize + 1
...
```